# Find if a given value is in a cell, if so then try next value until unique

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below sub that checks on a separate worksheet if the created number in textbox8 already exists, at the moment there is a message box that alerts the user that the part number already exists, they have to click OK, then the number is incremented by 1, the process is repeated until a unique number is found. This is the written to the worksheet along with some other data.

What I need to do is remove the message box so it will automatically search and find the next available number.

I added the following code to the sub, but this has no effect:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  MsgBox "This already exists"
  SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

code

```
'Create part number and check
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


With TextBox26
   If myreset = True Then
      .Tag = 0
      myreset = False
   End If
  .Tag = Val(.Tag) + 1
  .Text = "-" & VBA.Format(Val(.Tag), "0000")
End With


Dim iNum(1 To 8) As String
iNum(1) = TextBox24.Value
iNum(2) = TextBox25.Value
iNum(3) = TextBox26.Value


TextBox8.Value = iNum(1) + iNum(2) + iNum(3)

'check article exists

Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim rcnt As Long
Dim i As Long



ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("existing").Activate

rcnt = Sheets("existing").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To rcnt

If TextBox8.Text = Sheets("existing").Range("A" & i).Value Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  MsgBox "This already exists"
  SendKeys "{ENTER}"
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 Exit Sub
 End If
Next

Range("A1").Select
Do
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True
ActiveCell.Value = TextBox8.Text
```

Comment: Could you not just delete the msgbox line

Answer (score 0):

To remove the message Box all you need to do is delete the following lines in your code

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  MsgBox "This already exists"
  SendKeys "{ENTER}"
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I am not sure what the first part of the code is doing. if you could provide some example I can help with that. But I have rationalized the second part and this will now achieve what the original code was attempting to achieve with lesser lines.

```
'check article exists

Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim rcnt As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim varProdCode  As Long

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("existing").Activate
varProdCode = TextBox8.Text
rcnt = Sheets("existing").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Do Until varProdCode = 0
    For i = 2 To rcnt
        If varProdCode = Sheets("existing").Range("A" & i).Value Then
            varProdCode = varProdCode + 1
            Exit For
        Else
            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = varProdCode
            varProdCode = 0
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
Loop
```

Comment: I have removed the code for the message box, then it no longer appears, but the code will not loop until the next unique number is found, the user still has to run the sub by clicking on the "CommandButton2_Click" until the code is repeated enough times to find the required value. When the message box was clicked it will return to the first loop and increment the number by 1 and so on.

Comment: Looks like there are some inconsistencies with the code. let me fix it. ill update the code above

Comment: Actually I have a doubt. Are your trying to see if TextBox8 value exists and if it doesn't exist then set that as your product code and if it does then add 1 to that number and continue the loop till you find an unused value?

Comment: exactly textbox26 is the incremented value, textbox24 & 25 are taken from a lookup table, dependent on some dropdown boxes, and can vary.

Comment: unfortunately I now get a error 13, type mismatch on the varProdCode = TextBox8.text

Comment: Try one of the below either delete this line 'Dim varProdCode  As Long' or modify The line where it is breaking to varProdCode = CLng(TextBox8.Text) whichever works correctly as I'm not sure what the output of your text box is

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but neither work. Deleting the Dim VarProdcode just gives Compile error: Variable not defined, obvoisly as it is called two lines further down the code. If I leave this and modify the varProdCode = CLng(TextBox8.Text) then I still get the error 13. Im sure there is an easy way to sort this, probably something blindingly simple.

Comment: It might be that my premise is wrong. I thought TextBox 8 value is a Numerical value like 87343 but Im guessing its a concatenation of string. Can you share the string.

Comment: The string comes from                                                                         'Dim iNum(1 To 8) As String
iNum(1) = TextBox24.Value
iNum(2) = TextBox25.Value
iNum(3) = TextBox26.Value'.   Text box 24 and 25 are just numbers, but 26 has a - in it as well, 'With TextBox26
   If myreset = True Then
      .Tag = 0
      myreset = False
   End If
  .Tag = Val(.Tag) + 1
  .Text = "-" & VBA.Format(Val(.Tag), "0000")
End With'.    So the string would look like 501-0001

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works

```html
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


        With TextBox26
               If myreset = True Then
                  .Tag = 0
                  myreset = False
               End If
              .Tag = Val(.Tag) + 1
              .Value = VBA.Format(Val(.Tag), "0000")
         End With
         
        Dim emptyRow As Long
        Dim rcnt As Long
        Dim c As Long
           
        rcnt = Sheets("existing").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           
        For c = 2 To rcnt
        Dim iNum(1 To 8) As String
        iNum(1) = TextBox24.Value
        iNum(2) = TextBox25.Value
        iNum(3) = TextBox26.Value

        'check if article exists

          
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("existing").Activate
            
           If Sheets("existing").Range("A" & c).Value = iNum(1) & iNum(2) & "-" & iNum(3) Then
            TextBox26.Value = TextBox26.Value + 1
            iNum(3) = TextBox26.Value
            End If
             Next c
             
        'create article number
        
        TextBox8.Value = iNum(1) + iNum(2) + "-" + iNum(3)
            
        'select first column
        
        Range("A1").Select
```